# Finding AAR dependencies

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I am making use of a 3rd party SDK that is compiled into an AAR file. I want to use this AAR to create a bindings library for Xamarin.

How can I find the dependencies which this AAR uses? If I use a Java decompiler I can see that many of the classes have import statements for 3rd party SDKs, so I (sometimes) know which dependencies I need, but not which version or where to get them.

Ideally, I would like to find where in the AAR all these dependencies are defined so I can track them down and build my bindings library.

Comment: Is AAR published somewhere (maven central, jcenter)? Ideally, there should be a pom file generated when you prepare AAR for deploy. You can find transitive dependencies of your AAR in that pom file.

Comment: I did find the POM file, yes thank you. It lists about 5 dependencies. Is that all of them? What is the best way to track these dependencies down? If you add this as an answer I will mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is AAR published somewhere (maven central, jcenter)? Ideally, there should be a POM file generated when you prepare AAR for deploy. You can find transitive dependencies of your AAR in that POM file.

> Is that all of them?

Those dependencies might have other dependencies as well. Please read more about [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Comment: To answer the 2nd part of my question: I found all the dependencies by doing a Gradle Sync in Android Studio, and then all of them (including transitive), could be found in the %USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ folder.